# Slide two divs at the same time using Foundation's Orbit content slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider, zurb-foundation

[image: screenshot]

I need to animate/slide two div on a portfolio page (as per attached image, screenshot on both laptop and phone) simultaneously when the arrows are clicked. I can moderately understand/change JS plugins and am pretty proficient with HTML/CSS. Any recommended plugins or ways to do this without having to write specific JS code?

P.S I'm using Foundation framework from Zurb which has the 'Orbit' slider plugin built in, not sure that it's customizable enough to pull this off though

Comment: Well it can be done, but we need to see **your code** else we're completely in the dark. _Side note:_ You should edit your question with that info rather than commenting on it.

Comment: This is currently not supported in F4. You cannot change slides programatically, not without hacking it much. They even removed the callback function `afterSlideChange` that was in F3, that might help you hack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way of doing it but you can hack around. Say you have the following Orbits:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 columns">
        <ul data-orbit id="slider1">
            <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x350&text=slide 1" />                
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x350&text=slide 2" />                
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x350&text=slide 3" />                
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <ul data-orbit id="slider2">
            <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150&text=slide 1" />                
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150&text=slide 2" />                
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150&text=slide 3" />                
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can sync the sliding of the two Orbits by clicking on the navigation arrows, **provided that the two Orbits have the same `timer_speed`** (by default they will):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var fromSlide1 = false;
        var fromSlide2 = false;
        var slider1 = $("#slider1");
        var slider2 = $("#slider2");
        var slider1Prev = slider1.parent().find(".orbit-prev");
        var slider2Prev = slider2.parent().find(".orbit-prev");
        var slider1Next = slider1.parent().find(".orbit-next");
        var slider2Next = slider2.parent().find(".orbit-next");

        slider1Prev.click(function () {
            if (fromSlide1) return;
            fromSlide1 = true;              
            slider2Prev.click();
            fromSlide1 = false;
        });
        slider2Prev.click(function () {
            if (fromSlide2) return;
            fromSlide2 = true;
            slider1Prev.click();
            fromSlide2 = false;
        });
        slider1Next.click(function () {
            if (fromSlide1) return;
            fromSlide1 = true;              
            slider2Next.click();
            fromSlide1 = false;
        });
        slider2Next.click(function () {
            if (fromSlide2) return;
            fromSlide2 = true;
            slider1Next.click();
            fromSlide2 = false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Works perfectly in Foundation 4. Even works in WordPress with a no conflict wrapper. Thanks! Doesn't work in Foundation 3...

Comment: It's because F3 have different classes defined for Orbit. For example, in F3 the next button has a class `next` (orbit.next) while in F4 it's `orbit-next`.

Comment: When I tried this in F3 I get "no method 'foundation' " error on line 3. I am adding your script to the footer and foundation.min.js to the header. I tried moving your script to the header before foundation, but after jquery itself but I got the same error.

Comment: That's not how Foundation is initialized in V3. I think you should post another question as it's different than this one. And also so others can view it too and provide comments/answers. Would be hard for others to see your new issue if we talk about it here - through comments.

Comment: I just posted the question [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/q/15980783/1469799). Hopefully the answer to this will help me with the other Foundation related quest I am working on, which is to recreate the vertical navigation from F3 in F4. Not having that in F4 is why I'm not just solving the double orbit issue by moving to F4 on this project.

Comment: On-topic question: where would you add additional settings?

Answer (score 2):

The animation functions in jQuery works async so you can just call animation of the elements at the same time:

```
var deltaW = window.innerWidth;

$('#myDiv1').animate({left : deltaW});
$('#myDiv2').animate({left : deltaW});
```

You can also trigger a function when the animation is done:

```
$('#myDiv1').animate({left : deltaW});
$('#myDiv2').animate({left : deltaW }, function() { /*.. do something ..*/});
```

Edit: working example (please note the position attribute for the css-rule):
http://jsfiddle.net/2gCKY/1/

Comment: This doesn't really help with using Foundation's Orbit plugin.

Comment: @Jack Sorry, I have to +1.  In or out of Foundation's Orbit plugin, it doesn't get much easier than this.

Comment: @VoidKing I think his question is "How do I move to the next slide of two Orbit sliders simultaneously?" This doesn't help with that at all.

Comment: @Jack The question doesn't suggest this, but then again I'm not familiar with Orbit. If what you're saying is true, you're right, this wouldn't help, at all.

Comment: @VoidKing yes, that would optimally be the best solution is to use the Orbit slider to accomplish that, but as of right now I can't figure out how to do it so maybe some custom JS is the way to go