# How To Initialize Foundation 3 To Use Orbit?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit

I am trying to use a script I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15545241/1469799) to run Orbit in Foundation 3, but I can not get it to initialize properly. I added this script in the footer and Foundation.min.js in the header. I get a no method 'foundation'  error on line 3 in my console it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script in that SO thread you linked to will not work for your because it uses Foundation 4. Orbit is initialized differetly in Foundation 3 (F3). So suppose you have an element with id `orbitX`. You initialize it like this:

```
$("#orbitX").orbit();
```

In the other SO question you asked

> where would you add additional settings?

You do it when you initialized your orbit element like this:

```
$("#orbitX").orbit({
    bullets: false; // to hide the bullets
});
```

Here is the complete set of options

```
$('#orbitX').orbit({
  animation: 'fade',                  // fade, horizontal-slide, vertical-slide, horizontal-push
  animationSpeed: 800,                // how fast animtions are
  timer: true,                        // true or false to have the timer
  resetTimerOnClick: false,           // true resets the timer instead of pausing slideshow progress
  advanceSpeed: 4000,                 // if timer is enabled, time between transitions
  pauseOnHover: false,                // if you hover pauses the slider
  startClockOnMouseOut: false,        // if clock should start on MouseOut
  startClockOnMouseOutAfter: 1000,    // how long after MouseOut should the timer start again
  directionalNav: true,               // manual advancing directional navs
  captions: true,                     // do you want captions?
  captionAnimation: 'fade',           // fade, slideOpen, none
  captionAnimationSpeed: 800,         // if so how quickly should they animate in
  bullets: false,                     // true or false to activate the bullet navigation
  bulletThumbs: false,                // thumbnails for the bullets
  bulletThumbLocation: '',            // location from this file where thumbs will be
  afterSlideChange: function(){},     // empty function
  fluid: true                         // or set a aspect ratio for content slides (ex: '4x3')
});
```

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help Von. I found [this page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html) on initializing Foundation 4's Javascript buried in the docs. Do you know of a similar file for Foundation 3?

Comment: You're welcome. [This](http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/javascripts.php) maybe what you're looking for.