# How to disable Orbit timer in Foundation 4?

Tags: jquery, slider, zurb-foundation, orbit

I am using Orbit in Foundation 4 and would like to totally disable the timer function so slides can only be advanced manually by the user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(document).foundation('orbit', {
    timer_speed: 0
});
$(document).foundation();
```

Two calls are needed to initialize the other components of Foundation. Any customization should be done before Foundation itself is initialized.

Comment: Thanks again Von. I added this in front of the double slider script you provided in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15545241/1469799) and it gave me double arrows and bullet controls for both my regular slider and the double one. I took out line 4 and all was well.

Comment: Which line exactly? And did you mean all is working now? If not you can edit your question add the relevant code and I can take a look at it. And you're welcome :)

Comment: I was referring to `$(document).foundation();`. When I said 'all was well' I meant everything was working fine with Orbit, the timer was disabled, and Josh was a very happy boy.

Comment: Haha, well glad to be of help. But it was an interesting find though, I will have to check that out sometime this week.

Comment: If you're interested [this](https://gist.github.com/Shelob9/5402212) is what the script ended up looking like.

Comment: Cool thanks for sharing. Though I see you have to initialize each component individually. I am thinking that the rest of the components can be initialized in one go, if there are no customization for them. I'll find them for this, this weekend.

Comment: I tried to initialize everything else at once and nothing worked. No big deal as tooltips and orbit was all I was using.